# node.js node-modules' file path too long

Tags: node.js

I want to start learning node.js from Lynda.com ["Node.js Essential Training"](http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/Nodejs-Essential-Training/141132-2.html), but I cannot extract the exercises files' "node-modules" folder for chapters 09_03 and 11_06.

I get for example this:

```
!   C:\no\e.zip: Cannot create folder Ex_Files_Nodejs_EssT\Exercise Files\Ch11\11_06\start\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\htmlparser2\node_modules\domutils\node_modules\dom-serializer\node_modules\entities\maps
!   The filename or extension is too long.
!   C:\no\e.zip: Cannot create Ex_Files_Nodejs_EssT\Exercise Files\Ch11\11_06\start\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\htmlparser2\node_modules\domutils\node_modules\dom-serializer\node_modules\entities\maps\legacy.json
    Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 characters
!   The system cannot find the path specified.
```

How will I be able to make those exercises if I cannot extract the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you extract them without the `node_modules/` folder?

You don't have to extract the installed dependencies. Instead, there should be a package.json file and then you can install them by running `npm install` command (from cmd or git bash terminal).

Check also that you're running version 3 of NPM (`npm --version`). Then all dependencies will be installed flat (not nesting node_modules/) and that won't cause your issue.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I've shortened some archive folders inside winrar. I could then transfer on a windows directory, and renaming the folder back to original names.

Answer (score -2):

Try using a file extraction program like WinZip or 7Zip. It should allow you to redirect the extraction of certain files or folders to another location.